# GetOrgChart - load data that contain images take too much time

Tags: getorgchart

I'm using [GetOrgChart](http://www.getorgchart.com) to load data retrieved from json. In this json I have base64 images that are quite heavy, so to see my org chart I have to wait like one minute.

I try to load images separately on [renderNodeEvent](http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation#renderNodeEvent), but when I receive the image (with an asynchronous call) the org chart is already displayed and I'm not able to see the retrieved image.

Someone has any advice?

Thank you, Sara